# sh -c and exec works in prompt but not in Shebang script

Tags: shell-script, x11, executable, bspwm

I try to execute Xsession logout via shell script:

```
xfce4-session-logout --logout
```

The above option (or -l) allows logout without confirmation.

It works fine in bash prompt, but instead of sh, I have to use sh -c:

```
$> sh -c "xfce4-session-logout --logout"
```

exec works fine too:

```
$> exec xfce4-session-logout --logout
```

However I am not able to make it run in script. Theoretically, exec should work in script but while I put the code in script there is no logout action. 
On trying to catch errors with >> error.log 2>&1 , I found is no error message, while it is tested that other errors are able to be caught in the log.

Is there other way to a xsession-logout solution?
And if it is an error of xfce4-session-logout, where can I report this bug?

Caveat:
I used devuan - a systemd free distro, and I am not sure if it is related, e.g. xfce4 tools are built with some systemd dependency while the Devuan team might not have totally freed the influence of systemd on its distributed packages.

Comment: When you say you can't get it to do a logout if you run it in a script, _how_ exactly are you running the script? From the command line?

Comment: Does it work if you run it with `setsid xfce4-session-logout --logout`?

Comment: @Kusalananda
I defined a keybinding in my .config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc:  
     super + alt + Escape
     $HOME/.config/sxhkd/close_bspwm

and in the close_bspwm: 

    #!/bin/sh
    for window_id in $(bspc query -N); do
      bspc node $window_id -c
    done
    mpc stop
    if pgrep feh     &> /dev/null ; then killall feh;     fi
    if pgrep compton &> /dev/null ; then killall compton; fi
    if pgrep sxhkd   &> /dev/null ; then killall sxhkd;   fi

    bspc quit

    exec /usr/bin/xfce4-session-logout --logout

Comment: @Kusalananda
Edit: formatting doesn't work here.
So I defined a hotkey in my .config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc to trigger a bash script.config/bspwm/close_bspwm. Everything in that script runs except that line of xfce4-session-logout